# Azure AD - adding custom attributes

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Trying  to add Azure AD custom attribute and access custom attributes through claims (JWT Access token).

I tried using Azure AD Graph explorer but I got “Updates to converged application are not allowed in this version”.

Here is the request to add custom attributes

{

```
"name": "employeenumber",

"dataType": "String",

"targetObjects": [
    "User"
]
```

}

Idea is to

1)  Add custom attribute using Graph Explorer website-POST (Register extension)

2)  Set values for custom attributes suing Graph explorer – PATCH (Alternative use Graph service sdk)

3)  Modify applicant manifest of the Azure AD application and return the extension property as claims.

I’m stuck in Step 1.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application you have registered is v2.0 version(supports personal account).

Unfortunately, [Register an extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-directory-schema-extensions#register-an-extension--) only supports v1.0.

You can retry with a v1.0 application.

Microsoft strongly recommends that you use Microsoft Graph instead of Azure AD Graph API to access Azure Active Directory resources.

For how to add custom attribute to Azure AD user with Microsoft Graph API, please refer to: [Add custom data to users using open extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-open-users#1-add-roaming-profile-information).